# What actually happens when Process.Start(string,string) is entered?

Tags: vb.net, cmd

I have some vb.net code:

```
strScreenCalPath = "c:\Program Files\PenMount Windows Universal Driver\DMCCtrl.exe"
strScreenCalArguments = "-calibration 4"

Process.Start(strScreenCalPath, strScreenCalArguments)
```

From my understanding this code runs the DMCCtrl.exe file and passes it the     -calibration 4 arguments. How would this actually look if you typed it into a command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same as typing this in your commandline:

```
c:\Program Files\PenMount Windows Universal Driver\DMCCtrl.exe -calibration 4
```

It would run that from the `Environment.CurrentDirectory` with the same environment as your application. So if you run this in Debug from Visual Studio, it's likely like running from this commandline:

```
C:\MyProject\bin\Debug> c:\Program Files\PenMount Windows Universal Driver\DMCCtrl.exe -calibration 4
```

Comment: I see. Finally, got it to work. I have been trying everything. The code works, but I couldn't get it it to do the same thing from the command line to save my life. Your top line did the trick, but I did have to add quotes around the filepath. Thanks a bunch.